# What is the difference between soup.prettify and print(soup.prettify)?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying beautiful soup for web scraping, i am using jupyter notebooks. I wrote soup.prettify() and print(soup.prettify()), when i used the first one, the html did not get pretty print, however when i used it with print the HTML was printed in structured manner? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One displays the `repr()` of the formatted string, the other the `str()`.  The former is a debug format, so you can see unprintable characters, the other is the normal display format.

For example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
>>> s = soup('<html><body><p>blah blah blah</p></body><html>','html5lib')
>>> s
<html><head></head><body><p>blah blah blah</p></body></html>
>>> s.prettify()
'<html>\n <head>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <p>\n   blah blah blah\n  </p>\n </body>\n</html>'
>>> print(s.prettify())
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   blah blah blah
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note you can see the newlines as `\n` in the `repr()` version and the quotes around it indicating it is a string, all on one line.